# Heavy tail distribution in terms of the mean residual hazard function (proof)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, finance

I've been trying to prove the next characterization and looked in several books. But all of their proofs seem a little poor. In fact, many of them say that is easy and let the proof as an exercise. But I can't figure a nice way to prove it yet:

Let $X>0$ be a random variable with probability distribution function $F(x)$ and $\overline{F}(x):=1-F(x)$. We define the "mean residual hazard function" as:

$$
\mu_F(x):=\mathbb{E}(X-x|X>x)=\int_x^\infty\frac{\overline{F}(y)}{\overline{F}(x)}dy
$$

Proof that if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\mu_F (x)=\infty$, then $X$ is heavy-tailed.

Remember, $X$ is heavy tailed if its moment generating function $\left(\hat{m}_F (s)\right)$ satisfy:

$$
\hat{m}_F (s) = \infty \hspace{1cm} \forall s>0.
$$

The statement comes from the book: "Stochastic Processes For Insurance And Finance", page 68, Tomasz Rolski

Does anyone has any idea of how to prove it?